# Adding a column with an if else statement

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to cut numbers into categories to create a new column.  Basically, trying to create a letter grade ("A", "B", "C", "D", "F") from scores.

I have reproduced a similar data frame to the one I'm having trouble with in the following code.

```
df <- tibble(score = rnorm(20:100, n = 150))
```

The code I wrote to add the grade column looks like this:

```
df_with_grade <- df %>% 
  mutate(Grade = if (score >= 90) {
    "A"
  } else if (score >= 80){
    "B"
  } else if (score >= 70){
    "C"
  } else if (score >= 60){
    "D"
  } else {
    "F"
  }
  )
```

The code executes with a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (score >= 90) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (score >= 80) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (score >= 70) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (score >= 60) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The result is, all scores are assigned an "F"

Comment: Try using `case_when`

Comment: if one or more of these answers solves your problem, you are encouraged to pick the one you think is best and click on the check-mark ...

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
cut(df$score,breaks=c(0,6:10)*10,labels=rev(LETTERS[c(1:4,6)]))
```

? `rev(LETTERS[c(1:4,6)])` might be too clever and doesn't save *that* many characters over `c("F","D","C","B","A")` ...

Answer (score 4):

as suggested in the comments you can use `case_when`:

```
df_with_grade <- df %>% 
  mutate(Grade = case_when(score >= 90 ~ "A",
                           score >= 80 ~ "B",
                           score >= 70 ~ "C",
                           score >= 60 ~ "D",
                                     TRUE ~ "F"))
```

Comment: suggest changing `T` to `TRUE` (best practice)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use ifelse, it only works with binary conditions. Use cut like below,

```
df$Grade = cut(df$score,
breaks=c(0,60,70,80,90,100),
label=c("F","D","C","B","A"),
include.lowest =TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to show you can use `ifelse`.

```r
df_with_grade <- df %>% 
  mutate(Grade = 
ifelse(score>= 90, "A", 
  ifelse(score>=80, "B", 
    ifelse(score>=70, "C", 
      ifelse(score>=60, "D", 
        "F")))) 
    )
```

Comment: You can `nest` `ifelse` and it is also vectorized.