# Using mutate() and ifelse()

Tags: r

Very simple question. Is there any disadvantage to using the 2nd approach outlined below versus approach 1? Or are they effectively identical. (I'm partial to approach 2 as I deal with some complicated conditioning of variables, and find it easier to track piping the variable from one line to the next, but concerned that it might be poor coding practice)

```
library(dplyr)

section <- c("MATH111", "MATH111", "ENG111")
grade <- c(78, 93, 56)
student <- c("David", "Kristina", "Mycroft")
gradebook <- data.frame(section, grade, student)
mutate(gradebook, Pass.Fail = ifelse(grade > 60, "Pass", "Fail"))

#approach 1
mutate(gradebook, letter = ifelse(grade %in% 60:69, "D",
                           ifelse(grade %in% 70:79, "C",
                           ifelse(grade %in% 80:89, "B",
                           ifelse(grade %in% 90:99, "A", "F")))))


#approach 2
gradebook$letter<-NA
gradebook <- gradebook %>% 
  mutate(letter=ifelse(grade < 60, "F",letter)) %>% 
  mutate(letter=ifelse(grade >60 & grade< 69, "D",letter)) %>% 
  mutate(letter=ifelse(grade >70 & grade< 79, "C",letter)) %>% 
  mutate(letter=ifelse(grade >80 & grade< 89, "B",letter)) %>% 
  mutate(letter=ifelse(grade >90 & grade< 99, "A",letter))
gradebook
```

Comment: Even more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557792/adding-a-column-with-an-if-else-statement. `cut()` is often easiest to use. Not sure what type of "advantages/disadvantages". Choosing which one you like better is really just an opinion without specific criterial to assess.

Comment: I suppose I wanted to see if the assumption that each line in the pipeline is independent holds true. There are situations using approach 2 where I've found moving for example line 5 and 6, flipping it to line 6 and 5 make a difference in the results, even if the lines are essentially mutually exclusive as seen above (hard to replicate from complex datasets). I wanted to figure out if I am causing an instability of some sort with this code vs the recommended approach 1.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are some typo, but if you try using `dplyr::mutate`, in this case, `dplyr::case_when` will helps.

```
gradebook %>%
  mutate(letter = case_when(
    grade < 60 ~ "F",
    grade < 70 ~ "D",
    grade < 80 ~ "C",
    grade < 90 ~ "B",
    grade < 100 ~ "A",
    T ~ NA_character_
    ))

  section grade  student letter
1 MATH111    78    David      C
2 MATH111    93 Kristina      A
3  ENG111    56  Mycroft      F
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems much more efficient!